# Magento 1.9 . php_curl.dll and soap.dll is not loading

Tags: api, soap, curl

I am getting following errors on error_log file

> [26-Dec-2016 00:56:14 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_soap.dll' - /usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score -1):

the thing is you have a line:

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

somewhere in your php.ini or module .ini files.

search your .ini files for php_soap.dll and remove it.

```
find /etc -type f -exec grep -iHn --color=always 'extension.*php_soap.dll' {} \;
```

Comment: and same for curl.dll ?

Comment: yes the same steps for curl.dll